# Encrypting SFMC email link parameter values

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption

The email address of the subscriber is currently appended as a parameter to our SFMC email links. Rather than have the email as raw text, we would like to encrypt the value.

For example, the link url is now: http://www.test.com/?email=test@test.com
With encryption, it should be: http://www.test.com/?email=[encrypted value]

What would be the best way to achieve this? 
Note, we want to use encryption, because we need to decrypt the value as well.

**Addition:** Decryption needs to be done in node. So how can we encrypt in SFMC and decrypt in node?

Comment: Have you looked at [EncryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm) and [DecryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DecryptSymmetric.htm)?

Comment: Where will you be decrypting the value?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Node. Any example for this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Lookup : 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm

You will want to do something like this (using RedirectTo :

```
%%=RedirectTo(Concat('http://www.test.com/?email=', EncryptSymmetric(_emailaddr, 'AES', @null, 'password', @null, '0000000000000000', @null, '00000000000000000000000000000000'))=%%
```

Comment: Where is redirectTo added?

Comment: There are 3 ampscript functions in use here: 

Redirect () - used to tell SFMC that this is a link, which it can then track activity on

Concat() - concatenates the string of your URL with the encrypted value

EncryptSymmetric() - used for building your encrypted value

You will want to construct the url as above. Lookup the Salesforce Help guides for instructions in each function